# Script started minimized saves empty file

Tags: batch-file

I need to run script minimized and save it's output. I used following line but saved file is empty:

```
start /MIN script.bat > file.txt
```

How to start script minimized and save it's output to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outputting the results of `start` to file.txt.  The file is empty because `start /MIN` doesn't produce any output in the current console.  What you want is to have the file redirection as part of the started command.  Adding quotes fixes this.

Also, when I tried this, it created a new minimized command prompt which ran script.bat and then waited for further commands.  I assume this probably wasn't your intent.  To make the new console close after script.bat exits, pass the /c parameter to cmd.exe

```
start /MIN %comspec% /c "script.bat > file.txt"
```